# JBoss giving memory issues

Tags: java, jboss

I am using JBoss EAP 7.0 as application server for my Java application. Heap memory is continuously increasing with the JBoss related objects.

At one point, heap becomes full and runs continuous GC and slows down the application. Heap dump analysis  made us clear that some of the below JBoss objects are taking more memory on the heap.

```
io.undertow.util.HeaderValues
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange
io.undertow.util.HttpString
io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletRequestContext
io.undertow.util.HeaderValues
io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl
io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl
io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl
io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl
```

How could we go about this?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Where, in such cases, remote debugging is close to impossible. It is your server, it runs your code, so: you have to look further, and maybe directly talk to jboss experts. I really doubt that somebody can help based on such input from remote.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you have some kind of web application with sessions because of "io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager"

Check the following:
How much sessions are running before you go OutOfMemory?
How much data do you save in your sessions? (@SessionScoped)
How long is your session timeout?
When do you destroy your sessions? Logout?